# Clean way to get Windows PATHs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I need to check if `MY_PATH` exists in `Windows PATHS`, I do not mean about **PYTHONPATH**.

For example, if PowerShell PATH exists.
I know there is `sys.path`, but it returns only python paths.

Is there any clean way to check it?
I wrote code that works:

```
import subprocess as sp
out, _ = sp.Popen(["echo", "%PATH%"], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE).communicate()
assert any("MY_PATH" in path.decode() for path in out.splitlines())
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: `os.environ['PATH']`?

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) for that task as follows

```
import os
print("MY_PATH" in os.environ['PATH'])
```